# What does the `I` mean in `attrib` output?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, file-attributes

The following image is a screenshot after I typed `attrib` in C:

[image: Screenshot]

What does the `I` mean?

Comment: You can type `help attrib` for help on attrib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/34711), the `I` means:

> Not content indexed

Explanation is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2e432b39-bfe4-4031-ae4d-f0df6c2fb83d):

> This file cannot be searched by content. You can still search it by name.